# UNIX - separate file with delimiter condition

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a query in UNIX script. I have a file as below:

```
A|B|C|D|  
E|F|G|  
H|I|J|K  
L|M|N|  
O|P|Q|
```

I want to select records from this file with condition as 'only records with no 4th value' will be picked up. The result file should look like

```
E|F|G|  
L|M|N|  
O|P|Q|
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Also : Got one more problem with this: what if the line E|F|G| has a space after the last pipe (|). It wont select the line. We need to trim this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F '|' '$4 == ""' file
E|F|G|
L|M|N|
O|P|Q|
```

**Breakup:**

```
-F '|'   # sets input field separator as |
$4 == "" # selects only records that have 4th column empty
```

You can also use:

```
awk -F ' *\\| *' '$4 == ""' file
```

If there are spaces around `|` character.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy... It was quick and effective

Comment: Got one more problem with this: what if the line E|F|G| has a space after the last pipe (|). It wont select the line. We need to trim this?

Comment: Or even this: `awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' '$4 == ""' file`

Comment: Thanks again... It works fine for above example. But with the record I am working on, it fails. It seems there is some character (tab / new line ?) which is failing this. Is there a way trim everything around $4?

Comment: That might be `\r` (DOS line ending). Try: `awk -F '[\r[:blank:]]*\\|[\r[:blank:]]*' '$4 == ""' file`

Comment: This is also not helping... when doing VI with the file. I can see ^M added to the end of each file.. is this something we can take care please.

Comment: Run `dos2unix` before attempting this command. And I don't understand why you take such a long time to respond. btw the command I gave you works fine on a file with DOS line ending `^M`

Answer (score 0):

awk -F '|' '!length($4)' file
 
E|F|G|
L|M|N|
O|P|Q|